# Is it possible to merge two (or more) joysticks into one virtual one?

Tags: fedora, wine, joystick

With a more powerful graphics adapter comes the luxury of playing games in Linux (mostly using Lutris/Wine).

I have the classical bundle of CH Products joystick (Fighterstick, Pro Throttle and Pro Pedals) mostly for flight simulations. Most modern games support multiple joysticks and as such all is good there. However, this somewhat older game only supports one joystick. So, I was thinking to merge them together (like with the good old days using CH Control Manager) to create a single, albeit powerful, joystick to be used in the game.

Trying to install said software inside the Wine prefix unfortunately did not do anything (the joysticks were not detected by the software). So, I was pondering another approach: Binding the joysticks from the host platform (that is, Linux). I would use them almost exclusively together anyway.

Is this possible? If so, how? Looking online I found a few items for remapping buttons and the like (chiefly for Ubuntu), but nothing newer than 2016, which all seem abandoned projects.

If, on the other side, someone has experience getting CH Control Manager to work inside Wine would equally be nice.